# Low-hanging graphics programming fruits?

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d

I'm currently working on a tile-based game in Java2D, and I was thinking of adding some cheap eye candy.

For example, implementing a simple particle system (maybe something like [this](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/particles.html)) for explosions and/or smoke.

Do you have any suggestion for relatively easy to program effects that wouldn't require drawing a lot (or at all) of new art?

Tutorials and code samples for said effects would also be most welcome!

-Ido.

PS - if absolutely necessary I could switch to something like LWJGL/JOGL or even Slick - but I rather stay with Java2D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implementing blurs and other image filtering effects are fairly simple to perform.

For example, to perform a blur on a [`BufferedImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), one can use the [`ConvolveOp`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ConvolveOp.html) with a convolution matrix specified in a [`Kernel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/Kernel.html):

```
BufferedImageOp op = new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(3, 3,
    new float[] { 
        1/9f, 1/9f, 1/9f,
        1/9f, 1/9f, 1/9f,
        1/9f, 1/9f, 1/9f
    }
));

BufferedImage resultImg = op.filter(originalImg, resultImage);
```

Not quite sure when a blur effect is needed, but it may come in handy some time. But I'd say it's a low-hanging fruit for its ease of implementation.

Here's some information on [convolution matrices](http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/plug-in-convmatrix.html). It can be used to implement effects such as sharpen, emboss, edge enhance as well.

Comment: Motion blur can be made to look really nice in 2D and its very simple to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that!

Any more effects like that you know of?

Answer (score 5):

Performing a pixelation effect is a low-hanging fruit operation on a [`BufferedImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).

This can be performed in two steps:

1. Determine the color of the one block of the pixelation.
2. Fill in the block of pixelation on the image.

Step 1: Determine the color:

```
public static Color determineColor(BufferedImage img, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    int cx = x + (int)(w / 2);
    int cy = y + (int)(h / 2);
    return new Color(img.getRGB(cx, cy), true);
}
```

In the `determineColor` method, the pixel color from the center of the `BufferedImage` is determined, and is passed back to the caller.

Step 2: Fill in the pixelation block with determined color:

```
BufferedImage sourceImg = ...;  // Source Image.
BufferedImage destimg = ...;    // Destination Image.
Graphics g = destImg.createGraphics();

int blockSize = 8;
for (int i = 0; i < sourceImg.getWidth(); i += blockSize) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sourceImg.getHeight(); j += blockSize) {
        Color c = determineColor(sourceImg, i, j, blockSize, blockSize);
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillRect(i, j, blockSize, blockSize);
    }
}
g.dispose();
```

Although there is quite a bit of code, this effect is intellectually a low-hanging fruit -- there isn't much complex that is going on. It is basically finding the center color of a block, and filling a box with that color. This is a fairly naive implementation, so there may be better ways to do it.

The following is a before and after comparison of performing the above pixelation effect:

[image: Non-pixelated image] [image: Pixelated image]

Answer (score 1):

[Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) describes in great detail a number of very nice Java2D/Swing effects. It also gives an excellent theoretical background to these effects. I'm not sure how much low-hanging fruit there is, but it's a great resource for browsing.

One possibility might be to do something with alpha compositing. Maybe combine alpha composite with [Timing Framework](https://timingframework.dev.java.net/). Depending on the rules of your game, it might even be important to gameplay to selectively and time-dependently make objects semi-transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Transparency effects (e.g. for smoke) can make a big difference without too much effort.  No idea if this can be done in Java2d though.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that looks kind of realistic, things bouncing off of other things, rolling off, etc. can be kind of cool and if your game is a side scrolling 2D rather than top-down 2D you might be able to use a ready made physics engine like Box2D to do something cool with very little effort. Here's [a Java port of Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/wiki/index.php?title=JBox2d) that you could use for it.

Comment: I used Phys2D for stuff like that before.

Sadly it's a top-down game.

Comment: Ah well, it was worth mentioning. In that case I would definitely go the particle route. But ONLY after the game is finished enough to be playable. Getting it in people's hands to play is always your highest priority.