# How to pixelate a portion of an image

Tags: android, image-processing

I need some code on how to pixelate a portion of an image. Take, for example, someone's face or a number on a car's license plate. The basic idea is to reduce the size to say 30% and then zoom in 100%. Please help me if you can.

Comment: I think this solution would work for you:
[pixelate image in code][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547125/pixelate-image-in-code/30427318#30427318

Answer (score 1):

See [Low-hanging graphics programming fruits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976026/low-hanging-graphics-programming-fruits/976560#976560)

Comment: use the android sdk equivalent of BufferedImage. The algorithm is still the same.

Comment: dnt worry i've done it with the help createscaledBitmap()...using it twice did my trick...thnx anyways...:)